# Access container with Nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, centos7

I have a Centos 7 server. In this server i have Nginx.

In this sever i have a Docker with contain my app.

***App.yml:***

```
version: '2'
services:
    myBrand-app:
        image: myBrand
        environment:
            - _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx512m -Xms256m
            - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod,swagger
            - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://myBrand-postgresql:5432/myBrand
            - SLEEP=10 # gives time for the database to boot before the application
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
    myBrand-postgresql:
        extends:
            file: postgresql.yml
            service: myBrand-postgresql
```

It's possible to acces a Docker throught the Nginx Proxy through the ip of my server?

I want to use Nginx as a reverse proxy to the container

Comment: You want to use Nginx as a reverse proxy to the container?

Comment: @StuartBuckingham yes it is

Comment: Yes, you have mapped the port of your app container to the port of the server. You should be able to access it via `<server-ip>:8080` as long as the firewall settings allow access to the port.

Comment: @JackGore thanks, would you have an example of conf nginx file?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

Example docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    container_name: 'web'
    restart: always
    build: ./web
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    command: run_your_backend --port=8080

  nginx:
    container_name: 'nginx'
    image: "nginx"
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    links:
      - web:web
    volumes:
    - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Example of nginx config as proxy

```
upstream backend {
    server web:8080;
}


server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
    }
}
```